# I don't know what the problem is getting items using WISQL from Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I tired with the code below but somehow I don't get any data returned. 
When I debug it with Power shell SE, I don't think I can see if the personal token is accessible or not.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$url="https://dev.azure.com/MYproject"
$personalAccessToken="fdsafasdfdsafasd"
$project = "TEST"

GetWorkItems

function GetWorkItems
{
    # using env vars passed from VSTS build
    $collectionuri = $Env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
    $token = $Env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN # need to configure build to allow passing OAuth tokens

    $basicAuth = "{0}:{1}" -f "", $personalAccessToken
    $basicAuth = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($basicAuth)
    $basicAuth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($basicAuth)
    $headers = @{Authorization=("Basic {0}"-f $basicAuth)}

    $WorkItemType = 'Recently updated'

    $url = $collectionuri + 'DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.0'

    $WIQL_query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.IterationPath] Under 'Sprint number two' AND [State] = 'Active' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
    $body = @{ query = $WIQL_query }
    $bodyJson=@($body) | ConvertTo-Json

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -headers $headers -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $bodyJson

    $workitems = $response.workItems

    Write-Host "Found" $workitems.Count "work items of type:" $WorkItemType
}
```

Comment: Can you put this: `GetWorkItems` at the end of the script? You are calling this function before you are defining it.

Comment: Also, don't you think the the method on `invoke-restmethod` should be `GET` instead of post?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put this at the end of the script? You are calling this function before defining it.

```
GetWorkItems
```

The method on `invoke-restmethod` should be `GET` instead of `post`

Comment: so I deleted function and executed line by line and changed that invoke restmethod to get but it still getting message  `$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401243: The query test/wiql does not exist, or you do not have permission to read`

Answer (score 1):

Please try to define the parameters and modify the `$url` as the follows and try again:

```
Param(

   [string]$collectionurl = "https://dev.azure.com/MYproject",

   [string]$project = "TEST",

   [string]$personalAccessToken="fdsafasdfdsafasd"

)


 $url = "$collectionuri/$project/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.0"
```